# Troubleshooting transport layer connectivity issues with pfSense

Tags: networking, router, tcp, pfsense, proxmox

I am building a virtual network of vhosts that is NATed out to the internet through pfSense. For some reason, vhosts cannot establish connections to the outside world, although lower-layer operations like `ping` and `traceroute` are functional.

### The stack

[image: rough diagram of the setup]

- The physical machine is an Asrock Intel J4105-ITX board with 2 NICs (1 of them is a USB dongle).
- Proxmox 6.2-15 as the hypervizor.
- pfSense:

  - VM has 3 linux bridges connected:

    - `vmbr0` - bound to NIC1 which is connected to local /24 subnet with gateway to dynamic public ip
    - `vmbr1` - virtual 192.168.111.0/24 subnet for vhosts only
    - `vmbr2` - bound to NIC2 which is connected to a  /24 WAN with a static public ip
  - the interfaces assigned to `vmbr0` and `vmbr2` both have a gateway set and thus are treated as WAN type interfaces
  - outbound NAT mode is automatic
  - Only one firewall rule for vLAN interface: allow all packets from source vLAN net
- other vhosts

  - use vmbr1 as their network device and the pfSense ip (192.168.111.1) of that interface as their gateway.
  - I have tested a debian 10 LXC container and a Manjaro XFCE minimal VM. They exhibit the same networking issue

(*the reason for the confusing dual WAN setup is that other devices in the same subnet as `vmbr0` should eventually be able to connect locally, without routing through the internet. but this question is not about that*)

### The problem

Outgoing connections from VMs and LXC containers connected to the `vmbr1` Linux Bridge have functional low-level  networking but are unable to establish connections. That means:

- `ping 8.8.8.8` ✅ Works
- `ping pfsense.org` ✅ Works
- `traceroute pfsense.org` ✅ Works
- `curl pfsense.org` ❌ Connection timeout

### Observations

- Pretty sure that the problem is within my pfSense config. If I bypass pfSense, putting the vhost directly on one of the other bridges, networking works flawlessly.
- I tried completely disabling pfSense firewall (packet filtering), problem remains.
- I tried changing the default gateway
- pfSense itself has full connectivity, able to `curl` etc
- while DNS works from within the `vmbr1` LAN, it has excessive latency. Not sure if related
- state table for vhost->internet connections say `CLOSED:SYN_SENT` in the state column.

---

I don't understand what is going on there. By now I feel like I have read most of the pfSense manual, searched the internet up and down and tried everything I can imagine. Also I have set up a similar system before, and  normally it should simply work with the automatic outbound NAT...?

I hope somebody has an idea, because it is driving me crazy  Let me know if I should provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to enable the `Disable hardware checksum offload` option in pfSense Advanced / Networking settings.